# Copy Files from client machine to Hyper-V Core Host

Tags: powershell, share, virtualization, hyper-v

I would like to import some VMs into a Hyper-V 2012 Core Host (The VMs are Win 7 with different browser versions)

When I use the Hyper-V Manager GUI from my client machine to import the VMs, it only allows me to select files on the Host.  I have the VMs on my local client machine.  I would like to create a folder on the host and copy my VMs up there.

The host is Hyper-V Core, so I believe PowerShell is my only option.  I have, or can get, the necessary access I would need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a directory on the remote host and copy files to it via UNC paths (assuming the administrative shares are enabled and accessible on the remote host):

```
New-Item -Type Directory \\hypervisor\C$\some\folder
Copy-Item C:\local\vm \\hypervisor\C$\some\folder -Recurse
```

Provide alternative credentials via the `-Credential` parameter if necessary.

Comment: Had to enable File and Print sharing by running "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”File and Printer Sharing” new enable=Yes".  Then followed your PowerShell commands.